# Sending push-notifications from coldfusion?

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

DISCLAIMER: I have never used coldfusion before and am in a bit of a hurry to get a small code snippet implemented.

So, I have the app working and receiving notifications from a php script: device token is hardcoded into script, script has access to the needed certificate to encrypt the message using SSL, message is sent to apple servers and passed on to the device.

I need to do the same thing from coldfusion. That is what the production server is using.

Is there any way to do so from coldfusion, or will I have to use some other programming language to do so? I have read that coldfusion plays well with .net and with java. I would prefer .net, and I see they have the SSL stream class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) available. Could any coldfusion experts write some simple sample code to let me know how I should go about it?

Thank you.

-EDIT: in reply to the comment below, this is exactly what I want to do: connect through TCP over TLS or SSL to a server (in this case the Apple Push Notification server, APNs) using a local certificate I have in .pem format (if the certificate needs to be installed on the server or needs to be in another format for coldfusion, I can do that as well), and send it a binary stream (my notification).

Comment: This can probably be done with ColdFusion.  I use the word probably because it is not clear what you want to do.  Please elaborate on what type of notification you want, and to whom or what it gets sent.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? http://www.bennadel.com/projects/pusher.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, this can be done with ColdFusion.  In fact, it can be done with pretty much any programming language that has the requisite cryptographic libraries to open a private key store and sign messages to the destination server (i.e., Apple's push servers).

Though ColdFusion does appear to have some native support for accessing and using a PKCS12 keystore, it seems to be far more common to let Java do the heavy lifting, and simply reference the Java library from within ColdFusion.

Here is a link demonstrating the simple use case of initiating a push notification from ColdFusion, using a Java library for the actual sending of the notification:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/9/13/Guest-Post-Apple-Push-Notifications-From-ColdFusion-in-Ten-Minutes-or-Less

Comment: I actually got this working last night using this same method - using java to do the work and using the java objects in coldfusion. I was on my way this morning to post the solution here using the other java library I found (http://code.google.com/p/javapns/ for anyone interested). Thank you!

Comment: I guess a slight modification to your answer would be that it actually is NOT possible using coldfusion alone, as it does not provide the requisite libraries (from all the googling I did, please correct me if I am wrong), and thus this has to be done in java first.

Comment: *I was on my way this morning to post the solution here* @Bassel - Feel free to post your solution as an additional "answer" :)

Comment: @Bassel I guess it's a mix of terms. In essence, ColdFusion IS Java. Think of CF as nothing more than a framework / productivity layer for Java based web apps. Albeit, a rather nice one!